# How to track if the specific element exists?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button that dynamically creates a `TextBox` which is a representation for countdown timer, that deletes that TextBox `if (timerLife == 0)` and a button that can remove the associated TextBox. How can I keep track of which which TextBox still exists, so user can delete unwanted timer and a new one will be added on it's place?

```
int timerCount = 0;
int timerLife = 300;
int timerPos = 0;
int delBtnPos = 0;

public void StartTimer(int count, int life, TextBox container)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer
    {
        Tag = "timer" + Convert.ToString(count),
        Interval = 1000
    };

    Button delBtn = new Button()
    {
        Name = "delBtn" + Convert.ToString(timerCount),
        Width = 20,
        Height = 20,
        Text = "X",
        Location = new Point(67, delBtnPos),
    };

    delBtnPos += 24;

    delBtn.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        timer.Dispose();
        container.Dispose();
        delBtn.Dispose();
    };

    TimerContainer.Controls.Add(delBtn);

    int timerLife = new int();
    timerLife = life;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
    {
       if (timerLife > 0)
       {
           container.Text = Convert.ToString(timerLife);
           timerLife--;
       }
       else
       {
           timer.Enabled = false;
           timer.Dispose();
           container.Dispose();

           if (timerCount >= 6)
           {
               timerCount = 0;
               timerPos = 0;
           }
       }
    };
}
```

`StartTimer` adds the Button near the TextBox that can delete this TextBox and start the timer itself.

```
private void AddNewTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!timerExistence[timerCount])
    {
        timerExistance[timerCount] = true;
        TextBox txt = new TextBox()
        {
            Name = "timerBox" + Convert.ToString(timerCount),
            Width = 63,
            Location = new Point(0, timerPos)
        };

        timerPos += 24;
        timerCount++;

        TimerContainer.Controls.Add(txt);
        StartTimer(timerCount, timerLife, txt);
    }
}
```

`AddNewTimer_Click` is the event handler for the button that creates the initial TextBox. I thought that I could use an array of booleans and iterate over the array to check if any of the elements is `false`, so creating a TextBox would set the according boolean to `true` and deleting to `false`, but this creates another problem:

```
bool[] timerExistence = { false, false, false, false, false, false };

for (int i = 0; i < timerExistence.Length; i++)
{
    if (!timerExistence[i])
    {
        timerExistence[i] = true;
        TextBox txt = new TextBox()
        {
            Name = "timerBox" + Convert.ToString(i),
            Width = 63,
            Location = new Point(0, timerPos)
        };

            timerPos += 24;

            TimerContainer.Controls.Add(txt);
            StartTimer(timerCount, timerLife, txt);
        }
}

delBtn.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        timerExistence[count] = false;
        //...
    };
```

On first button click it creates all the timers at once and pressing the delete button near the first one somehow sets the last array element, according to the debugger.
Please tell if the question or my attempted solution is unclear.

Comment: I would suggest if i understand correctly to use a list of structs. The struct should have the *textbox handle, button handle, position and timerLife*. Use **one** timer and for each tick go throught the list and decrease the *timerLife*. You also check if *timerLife* for the specific element is zero and if so you dispose the controls and remove the struct from the list.

Comment: Could you provide some code example? I'm not very familiar with structs and lists yet.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε Also what do you mean by handles?

Comment: What is the max number of textboxes you can add? Are the positions fixed?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε Six boxes total, all fixed inside a `TimerContainer` panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said you need a list of structs. This is like a linked list of nodes:

```
public struct Node {
    public Button btn;
    public TextBox txt;
    public IntPtr hwndTxtBox, hwndBtn;
    public int position, timerLife;
}
public List<Node> list = new List<Node>();
```

Also set a variable for max number of controls:

```
private int maxCtrls = 6;
```

Now you need some functions to add and remove the controls:

```
private void Add() {
    //Find empty space, pos is basically the free line to add button and textbox
    //each line is seperated by 24 pixels
    int pos = FindPosition();

    if(pos < 0) {
        return; //no space
    }

    TextBox txt = new TextBox() {
        Name = "timerBox" + Convert.ToString( pos ),
        Width = 63,
        Location = new Point( 0, pos * 24 )
    };

    Button delBtn = new Button() {
        Name = "delBtn" + Convert.ToString( pos ),
        Width = 20,
        Height = 20,
        Text = "X",
        Location = new Point( 67, pos * 24 ),
    };

    delBtn.Click += ( sender, e ) =>
    {
        Remove( ( (Button)sender ).Handle );
    };

    TimerContainer.Controls.Add( txt );
    TimerContainer.Controls.Add( delBtn );

    Node node;

    node.btn = delBtn;
    node.txt = txt;
    node.hwndTxtBox = txt.Handle;
    node.hwndBtn = delBtn.Handle;
    node.position = pos;
    node.timerLife = 300;

    list.Add(node);
}

private void Remove(IntPtr hwnd) {
    int i;

    //find element in list to remove
    for( i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ ) {
        if( hwnd == list[ i ].hwndBtn ) {
            //delete button
            list[ i ].txt.Dispose();
            list[ i ].btn.Dispose();
            list.RemoveAt( i );

            return;
        }
    }

}

private int FindPosition() {
    int i, j;
    //check the first position that is empty 0 - (maxCntrs -1) lines
    for( i = 0; i < maxCtrls; i++ ) {
        //run all list
        for( j = 0; j < list.Count; j++ ) {
            if( i == list[ j ].position ) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if(j == list.Count ) { //position is found
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1; //not found
}

private void timer1_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    int i;

    //for all elements in list decrease timerLife. If timerLife is 0 then remove
    for( i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ ) {
        Node node;

        node = list[ i ];

        node.timerLife--;

        list[ i ] = node;

        if( list[ i ].timerLife == 0  ) {
            Remove( list[ i ].hwndBtn );
         }
        else {
            list[ i ].txt.Text = list[ i ].timerLife.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

To add textbox and button just write:

```
if( list.Count == maxCtrls) {
    return;
}

Add();
```

Comment: This is more complex than I imagined or would be capable of writing myself. I don't understand all of it, but thank you for your time, I'll try to wrap my mind around it.

Comment: @Gehrman On the contrary. This is very clean and easy. What part you don't understand.